# Extract source points in r.cost.full for each gridcell

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

[R.cost.full](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.cost.html) from the GRASS algorithm calculates an accumulated cost surface (i.e. a map of travel costs) for a unit cost layer/friction map. The output is a raster map where each grid cell has a value that represents the costs for getting to the closest source (e.g. the next town). Is there a possibility to extract which town is the closest source of each grid cell?

My intention is to get a second raster that contains the closest source (town) for all grid cells.

The manual states that by setting the parameter:
`outdir=name` I can create a raster `to contain movement directions`. However this is not what I exactly need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the options of r.cost exposed in QGIS processing, but if you run it in GRASS directly, r.cost has an output option *nearest*, which gives you a raster map where each cell has the value of the nearest point.

Comment: that's a good one. I don't know how I could oversee that. will give it a try. thanks!

Comment: works. one can eaven see the movement directions. I also saw that the option is available in the grass gui. I'm surprised that qgis does not implement all functions of the algorithm in its gui.